# Change the button pointer entered event in UWP using Interactivity

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to change the **background color** when the **pointer enter** in to the button.So I add the references Interactivity and Core. And my code is:

```
<Button Name="clickbutton" Height="60" Width="150"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="ClickButton" Margin="150,20,0,0" Foreground="Black" Background="Bisque" ClickMode="Pres
               <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior  Binding="{Binding PointerEnteredEvent ,ElementName=clickbutton}" Value="True">
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

But I didn't saw any changes in the run time. Is there any problem in my code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `DataTriggerBehavior`, which is inappropriate here. Use `EventTriggerBehavior` instead, which triggers when an event is fired (put the name of event into the `EventName` property without any suffixes).

```
<Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
   <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
```

If you want that the background of the button to become Green immediately on mouse enter, change the `EventName` to `PointerMoved`.
But I would recommend changing the Button's default template in order to achieve this.